# WKWebView, get all cookies

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, nshttpcookie, nshttpcookiestorage

I want obtain all cookies from WKWebView. Why? I have been started a project that use web-based auth. As result, I should intercept cookies to be sure that user is logged in and for some other purposes. Another case - imagine if user logged in, and than he "kill" the app - due to some delay in storing this cookie session will be lost :(.

> The problem seems to be that the cookies are cached and not saved out
>   to a file immediately.

(@Kemenaran from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15198874/2012219) - p.5 below)

The point where I try to catch them -

`webView:decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:decisionHandler:`,

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationResponse navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

  if let httpResponse = navigationResponse.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    if let headers = httpResponse.allHeaderFields as? [String: String], url = httpResponse.URL {
      let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(headers, forURL: url {
      for cookie in cookies {
            NSHTTPCookieStorage.shared.set(cookie)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but not all request are navigation, so one cookie (in my case) is skipped, see details below

[image]

Few words about other option I tried...

1. Yes, i Know that starting from iOS 11, we can use `WKHTTPCookieStore` as mention [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebsitedatastore?changes=latest_minor). But my project should support iOS 9+

[image]

2. I for 100% sure, that after 5-10 sec from login, required cookie will be saved to `NSHttpCookieStorage` (at least all my tests during few days confirm that)
3. I try to use provided observer `NSHTTPCookieManagerCookiesChangedNotification`, but it provide me callback only for cookies that comes within `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:decisionHandler`
4. I also try to get cookies using some JS like mentioned [here](http://www.luciendupont.com/category/apple/) and also test all suggestion from [here](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/WKWebViewTips) - really great article by the way. Result - negative
5. I also found this [radar bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2776403), and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15198874/2012219), and [Sample project](https://github.com/kemenaran/CookiesCrashDemo), but I want to prevent even this case. (described in this post applicable not only for remove but and for save) Also this situation true and when user kill the app, so case when user login, kill app and relaunch, may be present. And preventing this (simply by checking `NSHttpCookieStorage` for required cookies are also not good idea, because exactly after login required cookie can be stored with some delay, so this approach requires some `bool-powered` solution, that looks like weird..
6. I also read few more SO post for some related problem, and the most usefull are

   - [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2662530/2012219)
   - [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33156567/2012219)
   - [One more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39772007/2012219)

But still without good solution...

So, is any way exist to obtain or at least force to immediately store cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended with simple "force-like" saving Cookie from webpage.

To get all cookie i use

`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`

with JS string like `document.cookie();`. As result i able to receive all cookies as a string with `;` separator. All i need to do - parse string, create cookie and set it to `NSHttpSharedStorage`

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you won't be able to read the httponly cookies.

Comment: `  NSDictionary *eventInitDict = @{
    @"data": message,
  };
  NSString *source = [NSString
    stringWithFormat:@"document.dispatchEvent(new MessageEvent('message', %@));",
    RCTJSONStringify(eventInitDict, NULL)
  ];
  [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:source];
`

Comment: something like this